# Why was mutating style deprecated?

Tags: reactjs

The documentation in 0.13 and 0.14 both warn that mutating style has been deprecated, but don't mention why

> Reusing and mutating a style object between renders has been deprecated

What should I do if I want to perform state-dependent animations on an element that css class-based animations can't handle? Clone the object each time?

New to react, help and advice much appreciated

Comment: this answer did it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38199633/622287

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the test case/expected error, you are correct and should be cloning the object.

```
Warning: `div` was passed a style object that has previously been
mutated. Mutating `style` is deprecated. Consider cloning it
beforehand. Check the `render` of `App`. Previous style:
{border: "1px solid black"}. Mutated style:
{border: "1px solid black", position: "absolute"}.
```

[https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fc96f31fade8043856eb7bc34c56598c4a576110/src/renderers/dom/shared/**tests**/ReactDOMComponent-test.js#L128](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fc96f31fade8043856eb7bc34c56598c4a576110/src/renderers/dom/shared/__tests__/ReactDOMComponent-test.js#L128)

I would guess it's similar to the reasoning for props - it saves you from passing a mutable style object around everywhere and ending up losing a lot of the ease of reasoning that React is really good at helping you with.

`The props object is now frozen, so mutating props after creating a component element is no longer supported. In most cases, React.cloneElement should be used instead. This change makes your components easier to reason about and enables the compiler optimizations mentioned above.`

Answer (score 8):

You can work around this problem by copying the the previous style into a new variable and copying the previous style object.

**Example:**

***Not Allowed***

```
const {styleFromProps} = this.props;

const newStyle = styleFromProps['marginTop'] = '45px';
```

***Allowed***

```
const {styleFromProps} = this.props;

const newStyle = {...styleFromProps, marginTop: '45px'};
```

This way, you are not mutating anything, but just creating an new object from the previous one (i.e styleFromProps)

Answer (score 7):

Solving this problem is very simple.

**Bad way**

```
<div style={this.props.style} />
```

**Good way**

```
<div style={{ ...this.props.style }} />
```