# Object becomes read-only after the component rendered first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The issue occurs when I try to upgrade React 15.X to React 16.X:

```
let style = {
  width:12
};
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {

    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(style,'width'))

    style.width = 96;

    return (
      <div style={style}>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

outputs:

> - {value: 12, writable: **true**, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
> - {value: 12, writable: **false**, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
> - {value: 12, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false}

Anyone knows why the 'writable' becomes false?

Comment: What is `onChange`, it's not defined. And why are you trying to directly mutate a prop? I'm not sure why it changes to false after first render, but it probably shouldn't ever be writeable, it's a prop.

Comment: props are Immutable, if you want to update style on air, try do this with state within componentDidMount()

Comment: I edited the question. I copied the wrong code sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because mutating the `style` object is forbidden, and somewhere in the rendering process, `Object.freeze(style)` is called.

Ref:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11520#issuecomment-343731614
- [Why was mutating style deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295615/why-was-mutating-style-deprecated)

Object mutation in React has long been discouraged. `Object.freeze(props)` is enforced back in v0.x.x days. In v16 `Object.freeze(style)` is added.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want (๑ơ ₃ ơ)ﻌﻌﻌ♥